# How to calculate how many columns are null in particular row? in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have one table which contains a number of columns like 30-31 numbers.
I have to calculate % of how many null values in particular rows based on their id.
Please help me.
Thank You

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pivot the results on ID and do a `COUNT('X') - COUNT(X)` grouped by id..

But honestly I think I'd just do

```
SELECT
  (
    CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    ...
    CASE WHEN col31 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) / 0.31
FROM
  t
```

If you will be concerned that it's a lot of code to write, you could have the front end write it per table (do a `select * from table where 1=0` and build an sql using the column names for the returned resultset), or even SQL to write it, as most DB have some kind of tables that list all the columns:

```
--pseudocode because you never told us what your db is
SELECT CONCAT(
  'CASE WHEN ', columnname, ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +')
FROM alltablecolumns
WHERE tablename = 'x'
```

For example if you use MySQL, there is INFORMATION_SCHEMA - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html

Alternatively a good text editor like sublime can help because it can put multiple cursors so you type several lines of code at once.. describe the table, get the column names, paste on and make it to be on 31 lines, then hold middle mouse button and draw a line down the screen at the start of every word to put 31 cursors in, then just type CASE WHEN, press END, and type THEN 1 ELSE ...

[image]

Image credit: programmersought.com

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged the question PHP, so let me assume that you are using MySQL:

```
select t.*,
       ( (col1 is null) + (col2 is null) + . . .
         (col31 is null)
       ) / 31.0
from t;
```

You can implement similar logic in other databases, but MySQL conveniently treats boolean expressions as numbers, with `1` for true and `0` for false.